# ubuntu server can not turn off autmatic suspend

Tags: server, suspend

I have installed a vanilla desktop on ubuntu server 18.04. The automatic suspend is kept on all the time, and I can't switch it to 'off' option because it would just bounce back to the 'on'.

Is there any way to use command line to turn off Automatic suspend? ( I tried sysmctl mask, but it produces weird behavior. I asked about on another post but it got closed).

Thank you

Comment: "Automatic suspend" is usually a feature of your "vanilla desktop". Stock Ubuntu Server does not have such a feature enabled.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But in power management, I can't turn the automatic suspend switch to 'Off', it bounces back to 'On' every time.

Comment: That was a hint - we don't know which vanilla desktop power manager is enabled since you have not told us which desktop.

Comment: I think I misused the term vanilla desktop. It is a minimum desktop, no browser no other applications such libreOffice. In the beginning, I installed through sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, which didn't work then, the server was not showing GUI, everything was still commandline until I removed it through sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop. Restarted the server, it prompted me with GUI login and the desktop environment (blue background, no docking). Is there a way to find out which desktop?